# Uploading and storing image into private folder in php

Tags: php, image

The main objective is to upload an image and store in into a private folder named **uploadi**. The problem I am facing is the first time I upload it works, after that the image is uploaded but not stored in the folder.

Please help, thanks in advance.

```php
$Image = $_FILES["Image"]["name"];
$Target = "Uploadi/".basename($_FILES["Image"]["name"]);

if (empty($title)) {
    $_SESSION["ErrorMessage"]= "Title can't be empty";
    redirect_to("addnewpost.php");
} else {
    mysqli_query($con, "insert into admin_panel(datetime, title, category, author, image, post) values ('$dateTime', '$title', '$category', '$admin' , '$Image', '$post')");
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["Image"]["tmp_name"], $Target);
        if (mysqli_affected_rows($con) > 0) {
            $_SESSION["successMessage"]= "new post added successfully";
            redirect_to("addnewpost.php");
            exit;
        } else {
            $_SESSION["ErrorMessage"]= "failed to add category";
            redirect_to("addnewpost.php");
            exit;
        }
}
```

Comment: What errors do you get?

Comment: You should rethink the logic and check upload worked before inserting.

Comment: You are also open to sql-injection, use prepared statements.

Comment: is there any error you getting?

Comment: no, no errors are shown

Comment: can you clarify what prepared statements?

Comment: is sql injection the reason behind this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Problem comes from this `$Target = "Uploadi/".basename($_FILES["Image"]["name"]);`
This code mean that, for example you are on `\page1`, file will be uploaded to `\page1\Uploadi` and so on.

If the uploadi folder is in your web root directory, add `/` before it. Like:

`$Target = "/Uploadi/".basename($_FILES["Image"]["name"]);`

Like that, whenever you are on the website, your upload folder will be always the same

And, do not use "" for string, thisis not secure at all. use `'` with sprintf. Like:

`$Target = sprintf('/%s/%s', 'Uploadi', basename($_FILES["Image"]["name"]);`

Comment: still no change.....the image is getting added to the database but not to folder

Comment: Do you upload the same file? You don't check if the file already exists in your code

Comment: i did upload different files every time

Comment: whenever i type the same code then run it then the file gets stored but the moment i upload next image ....no storage

Comment: can you suggest some other way?